# Why are seaborn styles not working in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Up until recently when setting the style of my matplotlib plots, I would use seaborn-darkgrid. The below code worked fine for a long time but now it just shows the default style. I thought it was something wrong in my code but now that I look at the Matplotlib stylesheet reference page online, its seaborn style graphs are also showing up as the default style.

Are seaborn styles no longer supported by matplotlib.pyplot.style ?

link: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


%matplotlib inline

plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
dfLOADA = df_dayM[['InfNH3', 'EffNH3']]
plt.plot(dfLOADA)
plt.title('Influent and Effluent NH3: ' + month) 
plt.xticks(dfLOADA.index[::7])
plt.legend(dfLOADA.columns)
plt.xlabel('Time [days]')
plt.ylabel('[mg NH3/L]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does `sns.set_style('darkgrid')` also not work?

Comment: Works for me. Restart your notebook. *Restart Kernel and Clear All Outputs...*

Comment: Tried restarting the kernel as well as clearing all outputs but nothing. sns.set_style('darkgrid') also did not work. Actually now that I think about it, it worked on my Mac but may never have worked after switching to a PC. I'm most confused as to why the matplotlib stylesheet webpage itself would look different between the Mac and PC.

Comment: Try updating your packages. If using Anaconda, then at the conda prompt `conda update --all` is simplest. As to why, maybe the package versions are different between the two systems.

Comment: Still, code like `mpl.rc_params_from_file("seaborn-darkgrid",True,False)` fails now because of the rename.

Comment: It looks like _matplotlib_ calls that one "seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid" now.  Other names, like "seaborn-notebook", have changed similarly.

Comment: Setting `sns.set_style()` does nothing.